# Catch the value returning from Django in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have created a django API, which is returning a json object. And then I have a separate web application from which I am calling the django API. Now I want to store/catch the returned Json object in my HTML/Javascript.

Here's the code I am using

**HTML Code**

```
<div >
    <form acton="http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/export" method="POST">
        <label class="optinLabel">Project Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="confirm your project name"/>
        <label class="optionLabel">Downlaod</label>
        <input  type="submit" value="Json" style="color:red" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Django** `views.py`

```
def export(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        projectname = request.POST.get('projectname')
        folderpath = "/home/data"
        finalpath = os.path.join(folderpath,projectname)
        json_result = ann_json(finalpath)

    return JsonResponse({"response":json_result})
```

Here the `view.py` returning the Json, how will catch that in my HTML Code?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to store your data in a variable or use `localStorage` to cache the data, and to get the data from your API I recommend to use fetch API.

```
fetch('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/export')
        .then((response) => return response.json())
        .then((data) => {
                localStorage.setItem('data', data)
        })
```

but as far as I'm concerned using API is mostly used for web applications, not just regular website

Comment: The API is consume by a web application only. and in that I am trying to get the value inside a html file which is a part of the web application. I tried your solution but it is showing Error code 501.

Comment: note that you don't have projectname as a value of the name props of your input element